# How to transfer POJO object to Ignite table?

Tags: json, caching, apache-kafka, ignite, pojo

```
public class JSONmapper {
    public static class Person{
        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
            int id;
        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
            String name;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Object> serdeProps =  new HashMap<>();
        serdeProps.put("json.value.type",Person.class);
        final Deserializer<Person> PersonDeserializer = new KafkaJsonDeserializer<>();
        PersonDeserializer.configure(serdeProps, false);

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, PersonDeserializer.getClass().getName());
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"JSONmapper1");
        prop.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");
        KafkaConsumer<String,Person> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(prop);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("JsonMapper1"));

        IgniteConfiguration config = new IgniteConfiguration();
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(config);

        CacheConfiguration<String, Person> cc = new CacheConfiguration<>("PersonCache");
        cc.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
        cc.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
        cc.setIndexedTypes(String.class,Person.class);
        IgniteCache<java.lang.String,Person> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cc);

        Map<String, Person> batch = new HashMap<>();
        while(true)
        {
            ConsumerRecords<String, Person> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, Person> record:records){
                batch.put(record.key(),record.value());
            }
            cache.putAll(batch);
            batch.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Hi all I am trying to send JSON data coming out of Kafka to Ignite cache and view it as a table. After running this code I could observe that data is transferred to cache, confirmed this with visorcmd. I triggered sqlline.bat from setup with PersonCache schema as it was showing !tables. But unable to query "Select * from Person". It is giving me error that "Failed to set schema for DB connection for thread".

Please enlight and help regarding this.

```
SEVERE: Failed to execute SQL query [reqId=2, req=JdbcQueryExecuteRequest [schemaName=PERSONCACHE, pageSize=1024, maxRows=0, sqlQry=select * from PersonCache.PERSON, args=Object[] [], stmtType=ANY_STATEMENT_TYPE, autoCommit=true, partResReq=false, super=JdbcRequest [type=2, reqId=2]]]
class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to set schema for DB connection for thread [schema=PERSONCACHE]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2ConnectionWrapper.connection(H2ConnectionWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.QueryParser.parseH2(QueryParser.java:319)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.QueryParser.parse0(QueryParser.java:210)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:131)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.querySqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$3.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2406)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$3.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2402)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2919)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.lambda$querySqlFields$1(GridQueryProcessor.java:2422)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuerySafe(GridQueryProcessor.java:2460)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2396)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2354)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.executeQuery(JdbcRequestHandler.java:615)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.doHandle(JdbcRequestHandler.java:310)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.handle(JdbcRequestHandler.java:247)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:195)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "PERSONCACHE" not found [90079-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getSchema(Database.java:1808)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.setCurrentSchemaName(Session.java:1317)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.setSchema(JdbcConnection.java:1989)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2ConnectionWrapper.connection(H2ConnectionWrapper.java:76)
    ... 25 more
```

At SQLline end :

```
Error: Failed to set schema for DB connection for thread [schema=PERSONCACHE] (state=50000,code=1)
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to set schema for DB connection for thread [schema=PERSONCACHE]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:901)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:231)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute(JdbcThinStatement.java:559)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:823)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:733)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:795)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265)
```

Comment: Doing `select * from PersonCache.Person` should work. If not, please share the _full_ error, including the stack trace on the server side.

Comment: Can you please check I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in order to have an Apache Ignite SQL table based on some POJO, you must do one of the following:

1)If you are going to configure the cache via XML, you must create a custom QueryEntity based on the required POJO types:

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-api#query-entities

Or you can use special annotations in your POJO object:

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-api#querysqlfield-annotation

2)Using SQL syntax, you must set the correct key and value types using the following properties:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person (
  id int,
  city_id int,
  name varchar,
  age int,
  company varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, city_id)
) WITH "template=partitioned,backups=1,affinity_key=city_id, key_type=com.test.PersonKey, value_type=com.test.MyPerson"
```

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/ddl